# How to insert data in to datatstore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

How to insert data in to datastore?
The data could be like the one below:

```
{
  'food': [{
    "item_name": item,
    'price': price
  }, {
    "item_name": item,
    'price': price
  }],
  'beverages': [{
    ''
    'beverage_name': beverage,
    'beverage_price': b_price
  }, {
    ''
    'beverage_name': beverage,
    'beverage_price': b_price
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data that you are trying to add to the `Google Cloud Datastore` is a `JSON` string. The way you have it in your question is wrong structured. The proper `JSON` example would be:

```
{
  "food": [
    { "food_name":"NAME1", "food_price":"PRICE1" },
    { "food_name":"NAME2", "food_price":"PRICE2" },
    { "food_name":"NAME3", "food_price":"PRICE3" }
  ],
  "beverages":[
    { "beverage_name":"NAME1", "beverage_price":"PRICE1" },
    { "beverage_name":"NAME2", "beverage_price":"PRICE2" }
  ]
}
```

To add the data from the JSON string to the Datastore you have to:

1. Load the JSON string as JSON object to be able to go through its fields
2. Create a client to access Google Datastore
3. Set the key `food` for the `Kind` value in Datastore
4. Use the `entity` to add the data to the Datastore
5. Set the key `beverages` for the `Kind` value in Datastore
6. Use again `entity` to add the data to the Datastore

For further information, you can refer to [Google Cloud Data Store Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) documentation.

I have done a little bit coding myself and here is my [code example in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Entities-Python/save_json_data_to_datastore.py) for Python. You can take the idea of how it works and test it. It will create two different `Kind` values in Datastore and add the food data in `foods` and beverage data to `beverages`.